# "Object" object typecast and reference to "Some" class Object

Tags: java, object, casting

Why am I not able to reference object of "Object" class typecasted and referenced to Some class's object. Following code explains it. It is hard to put in words. Meaning, object of Super class Object should be able to reference any type of Class's object.

```
public class ChildClass {

public static void main(String[]args){
    Simple obj1=new Simple();
    Object obj2=(Simple)obj1;
    System.out.println("1-obj1.a is "+ obj1.a+" obj1.name is "+obj1.name);
    System.out.println("2-obj2.a is "+ obj2.a+" obj2.name is "+obj2.name);/*a cannot be resolved or is not a 
    field*/
    doSomething(obj2);
    System.out.println("3-obj2.a is "+ obj2.a+" obj2.name is "+obj2.name);/*a cannot be resolved or is not a 
    field*/
    System.out.println("4-obj1.a is "+ obj1.a+" obj1.name is "+obj1.name);
}

private static void doSomething(Object obj2) {
    obj2.a=99;//a cannot be resolved or is not a field
    obj2.name="new name";//name cannot be resolved or is not a field

}
class Simple {

    int a=9;
    String name="something";

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `Object` to `Simple` if you really want the argument to be of type `Object`:

```
private static void doSomething(Object obj2) {
    ((Simple)obj2).a = 99;
    ((Simple)obj2).name = "new name";
}
```

or, to make it a little more safe:

```
private static void doSomething(Object obj2) {
    if (obj2 instanceof Simple) {
        Simple simple = (Simple) obj2;  
        simple.a = 99;
        simple.name = "new name";
    }
}
```

You seem to have it backwards. A reference of type `Simple` can be used to call methods of `Object`, but not the other way around.

Comment: System.out.println("2-obj2.a is "+ ((Simple)obj2).a+" obj2.name is "+((Simple)obj2).name);
It says "No enclosing instance of type ChildClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ChildClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ChildClass)." at Simple obj1=new Simple();

Comment: From this example I am trying to create reference of Object class point it to "Some" class object and then alter members of "Some" class

Comment: @RandonP: Move `Simple` outside of `ChildClass` to resolve that issue.

Comment: Or rather @DavidPrun, but I guess you got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do what Keppil above suggests.

Or, because you are casting obj2 to the type Simple, just change doSomething's parameter to that type:

```
private static void doSomething( Simple simple ) { 
    simple.a=99;
    simple.name="new name";
}
```

You should also change

```
Object obj2=(Simple)obj1;
```

to

```
Simple obj2 = (Simple)obj1;
```

Comment: From this example I am trying to create reference of Object class point it to "Some" class object and then alter members of "Some" class

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference fields which exist in an instance of class Simple, but you are not type casting the object to an instance of Simple.

Variable obj2 has been assigned to hold an instance of Simple, but its been declared as type Object.  If its not explicitly cast to type Simple, the compiler can only assume obj2 has the functions that type Object has.

I haven't tested this code, but it should get the point across.  Note I'm casting obj2 to type Simple whenever I reference any field declared in type Simple.

```
public class ChildClass {

public static void main(String[]args){
    Simple obj1=new Simple();
    Object obj2=obj1;
    System.out.println("1-obj1.a is "+ obj1.a+" obj1.name is "+obj1.name);
    System.out.println("2-obj2.a is "+ ((Simple)obj2).a+" obj2.name is "+((Simple)obj2).name);
    doSomething((Simple)obj2);
    System.out.println("3-obj2.a is "+ ((Simple)obj2).a+" obj2.name is "+((Simple)obj2).name);
    System.out.println("4-obj1.a is "+ obj1.a+" obj1.name is "+obj1.name);
}

    private static void doSomething(Simple obj2) {
        obj2.a=99;//a cannot be resolved or is not a field
        obj2.name="new name";//name cannot be resolved or is not a field
    }
    class Simple {
        int a=9;
        String name="something";
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println("2-obj2.a is "+ ((Simple)obj2).a+" obj2.name is "+((Simple)obj2).name);
It says "No enclosing instance of type ChildClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ChildClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ChildClass)." at Simple obj1=new Simple();